Harmonic function in a square
I'm trying to find harmonic function $u(x,y)$ in a square $\Omega$ = {$ 0<x< \pi, \; 0 < y < \pi $} with boundary conditions $u(0, y) = u(\pi, y) = 0, u(x,0) =0, u(x, \pi) = 2 \sin(x) - \sin(2x)$.
Using method separation of variables, where $\lambda = \beta^{2}$, I got
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda$$
The equation are
$$X(x) = A\sinh(\beta x) + B\cosh(\beta x), \quad Y(y) = C\sin(\beta y) + D\cos(\beta y)$$
$u(x,y) = (A\sinh(\beta x) + B\cosh(\beta x)(C\sin(\beta y) + D\cos(\beta y))+A_{0}x$, which after applying boundary conditions doesn't seem right, the beta is equal to $\beta = in$ and $A_{0}$ is vanishing. Is it correct? What I am missing?
Is $\lambda$ can be negative and the solutions for $X(x)$ switch to cosine, sine for $X(x)$?

Try the ansatz $u(x,y)=f(y)\sin(x)+g(y)\sin(2x)$.

Please note that you can use \sin, \cos, \sinh, \cosh for $\sin,\cos,\sinh,\cosh$ (resp.)

Hint 1: What are the possible values of $\beta$. Hint 2: Can you combine solutions corresponding to different values of $\beta$ into a new solution in a simple way?

@whpowell96 I've explained more clear what I am thinking of.

As suggested in my comment, let's try the ansatz
$$
u(x,y)=f(y)\sin(x)+g(y)\sin(2x). \tag{1}
$$
Notice that $(1)$ satisfies the boundary conditions $u(0,y)=u(\pi,y)=0$. It also satisfies the boundary conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(x,\pi)=2\sin(x)-\sin(2x)$ if
$$
f(0)=g(0)=0,\quad f(\pi)=2, \quad g(\pi)=-1. \tag{2}
$$
In addition, when we plug $(1)$ into Laplace's equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, we get
$$
[-f(y)+f''(y)]\sin(x)+[-4g(y)+g''(y)]\sin(2x)=0
$$
$$
\implies f''(y)-f(y)=0\quad\text{and}\quad g''(y)-4g(y)=0. \tag{3}
$$
Therefore, if the ODEs $(3)$ have solutions that satisfy the boundary conditions $(2)$, we are done. Such solutions indeed exist; they are
$$
f(y)=2\frac{\sinh(y)}{\sinh(\pi)}\quad\text{and}\quad g(y)=-\frac{\sinh(2y)}{\sinh(2\pi)}. \tag{4}
$$
The combination of $(1)$ and $(4)$ yields the desired harmonic function.
